# How to remove <div> when export excel where is no data?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, gridview

How to remove the `<div>` tag in Excel when I try to export empty data? When it contains data the `<div>` tag does not exist, it exists when the data is empty, I want to remove the tag how do I do that?

This is my export code

```
public void ExportExcel_AccountInfo(string Prmreportdate, string PrmBranch, string prmdrpdown_sort, string PrmWilayah)
{  
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        string thisDATE = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        var namafileparam = "Report_Account_Information_Konven_" + thisDATE;
 
        var gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = this.GetAccountInfoList(Prmreportdate, PrmBranch, prmdrpdown_sort, PrmWilayah);
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+namafileparam+".xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);

        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[i];
            //Apply text style to each Row
            gv.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
        }

        gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);

        Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();  
}
```

or if data is empty can I add text in excel like "data not found?"

Comment: What is `GetAccountInfoList()`? Does it do any transformation on empty data?

Comment: it get list of the data